# VPS Providers With Instance APIs

Tags: vps, cloud, cloud-hosting

My company is trying to find a list of VPS / cloud providers who offer an instance API to create new instances, tear down old instances, and get new IPs / etc. We're trying to make our platform instantly scalable via statistics, etc.

I'm having an extremely hard time finding API information for a lot of the VPS / cloud providers that I know, so I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone could contribute.

So basically, please suggest some VPS / cloud providers with instance APIs, as well as any thoughts / comments about them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [libcloud](http://incubator.apache.org/libcloud/) project. All the providers supported obviously have an API, but using libcloud means that you can make your implementation fairly provider-agnostic.